# How to pass value from DropDownListFor to angular function?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have this dropdown list:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectCountryId, Model.Countries, @Translator.Translate("PLEASE_SELECT"), new { id = "CountryID", @class = "form-control", ng_click = "LoadRegions();", @required = "required" })
```

How can I pass value `m=>m.SelectCountryId` to 
`ng_click = "LoadRegions(SelectCountryId)"` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out... just put:

```
ng_model = "countryId"
```

And then:

```
ng_click = "LoadRegions(countryId)"
```